# Why is the Ocean Blue?

Tags: waves, visible-light, water, molecules, harmonics

I'm writing an article on the physical property that binds Music and Water -- Harmonics. I understand that the blueness of ocean water is due to the three vibrational modes of water (i.e, symmetric, asymmetric, and bending), and these three modes are somehow related to the harmonics, but I don't quite understand how. As you can see, it states that $\rm H_2O$ has some harmonics in part C. Here's the image I'm referring to:

[image]

Although Niels' answer does mention the fact that water has three fundamentals, I still don't quite see the relationship between the fundamentals of each of water's vibrational modes and harmonics. I would appreciate both a qualitative and a bit of quantitative-based answer.

Comment: What is a "water harmonic"?

Comment: You would probably find [this page](http://www.webexhibits.org/causesofcolor/5B.html) useful.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. @MichaelSeifert I've actually read that page, and it was part of the inspiration behind this question.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing waves, resonance, and in particular harmonics, which makes your questions a bit hard to understand.

A wave has a fundamental frequency- for instance, the note A's fundamental is at 440 vibrations per second.  You can add to that fundamental other waves at higher frequencies which have their "endpoints" coincident with the endpoints of the fundamental; what you get then is called a *harmonic series* of tones that are *based* on the fundamental. the harmonics add color and richness to the fundamental which is why a plucked string (which is rich in harmonic content) does not sound like a pure tone (as from a tuning fork for example).

A water molecule has three different *fundamental modes* or *resonances* which are not *harmonics* of each other; they represent different ways in which the molecule can vibrate. Modes like this are *not* "related to the harmonics"; they are separate fundamentals that the molecule can possess at the same time because the molecule possesses separate *degrees of freedom* in which it can be excited to produce fundamentals for each mode. A string can possess only one resonant mode because unlike the molecule, it has only one degree of freedom.

A water molecule happens to have resonant mode frequencies which coincide with frequencies in the red end of the visible light spectrum, which means that sunlight that passes through a body of water has the red colors captured and removed from the beam when they excite one or more of the water molecule's resonant modes. this absence of red then tints the water blue-green in color.

Since resonating bodies produce sound waves with different harmonic content, it is completely natural that the physics of music are completely dependent on modes and harmonics.

All molecules contain mass and springiness and so all of them will potentially exhibit resonances in different modes of vibration- and hence interact with light of different wavelengths (i.e., color). This allows chemists to positively identify the presence of tens of thousands of different molecules by shining light on them and seeing which frequencies are absorbed out of the beam. Most molecular resonances occur in the infrared range of light, which humans cannot see but for which exquisitely sensitive detectors can be built, giving rise to the field of *infrared spectroscopy* as a tool for detecting the presence of and identifying the contents  of mixtures containing chemicals.

Comment: great answer. To summarise is for the OP: you are looking for something that isn’t really there.

Comment: It is interesting that for several decades of my life I have thought that water is colorless and the ocean is only blue due to it reflecting the blue sky (a school teacher told us this, buyer beware!). Until I recently had the chance to christen my new (neutral white) bathtub in my new daylight bath with pure tap water. And guess what, even 20 cm of depth are pretty well enough to notice the slightly bluish color under these circumstances. I didn't ever notice this before, because under artificial light the bluish color gets masked by the yellow tint of light. What a big surprise for me!

Comment: @oliver Discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water#Vibrational_spectrum).

Comment: I've modified my question slightly after reading Niels' insightful answer. In addition, @J.G. this is a great link! I have not seen this. I will read more into it.